# Sliding multi bar chart in the horizontal with nvd3.js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to plot a multi bar chart, where each bar pair means the value of the month in this year (one bar) and in the previous year (another bar). There will be 12 bar pairs, a par for each month.

I want that the month I choose would show as the last bar, so if I choose april, it will show: may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec, jan, feb, mar, apr.

So far, so good, I can achive that returning the json in this order.

The problem is that when I change the month and update the chart, the bars should move, but they does not move like I want. I want them to slide in the horizontal, but instead, each bar adjust their height so that in the end each position would be ok, but the visual effect is not good.

I believe I need to set the "key" of each bar, but I'm unable to do it.

here is the relevant code:

```
    d3.json(json, function(data) {
    nv.addGraph(function() {
        var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
            .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
            .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
            .color(colors)
            .forceY([0, 100])
            .reduceXTicks(false)
            .stacked(false)
            .showControls(false)
            .margin({left: 50, right: 30});

        chart.xAxis
            .showMaxMin(false)
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                return ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'][d - 1];
            });

        chart.yAxis
            .tickFormat(function(n) {
                return d3.format('.0f')(n) + '%';
            });

        d3.select("#" + id + " .view svg")
            .data([data]/***, function(d, n) {
                return "x";
            }***/)
            .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you put the code on a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so people can get a better idea of what you are trying to achieve and help you out.

Comment: Here is it http://jsfiddle.net/0zsdmpd2/2/  Note the X-axis labels moves like I want, but the bars not. I want the bars to move from left/right too, instead of adjust top/height.